# Inter app model import in Django

Tags: python, django, import, importerror, valueerror

[File tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlPbP.gif)

I'm struggling with inter app model importing in Django

I've had a look at others who have asked the same sort of question and the answers have not satisfied my problem

my file structure is:

```
welted_website

-cart
--views

-shop
--models
```

There's a clickable link to the full file tree image at the top also

I'm trying to import Product from my shop.models into cart.views but to no avail!

I've tried

```
from ..shop.models import Product

from welted_website.shop.models import Product
```

The second of which gave me the following:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

My apps contain `__init__.py` files by default

shop and cart have been added to INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'shop',
'cart',
```

)

Comment: *"I've had a look at others who have asked the same sort of question"* - which? *"and the answers have not satisfied my problem"* - how, specifically?

Comment: Did you tried `from shop.models import Product` ?

Comment: That's what should originally work, but it's not!

Answer (score 0):

Install the apps in your settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'shop',
)
```

import Product

```
from shop.models import Product
```